# Как за номером дня недели вывести его название?

Tags: pascal, case

Как через оператор `case` за номером дня недели вывести на экран его название руским языком?

Comment: А нужен ли тут оператор `case`? сложите дни недели в массив (список) и доставайте по номеру.

Answer (score 1):

```
   case x of:
1:writeln('Понедельник');
2:writeln('Вторник');
3:writeln('Среда');
4:writeln('Четверг');
5:writeln('Пятница');
6:writeln('Суббота');
7:writeln('Воскресенье');
```